# Failed REST request: grid is empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a dummy grocery app and i've encountered an issue that it's starting to be frustanting at this point.
The issue lies when i try to load grocery products from the backend. By making a request i'm expecting all the backend products in return, but instead i get an empty grid.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've tried everything that i know, can you guys help me?

```
Here it is the endpoint:

String baseUrl = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/functions";

abstract class EndPoints {
  static String signin = "$baseUrl/login";
  static String signup = "$baseUrl/signup";
  static String validtoken = "$baseUrl/validate-token";
  static String resetPassword = "$baseUrl/reset-password";
  static String getAllCategories = "$baseUrl/get-category-list";
  static String getAllProducts = "$baseUrl/get-product-list";
}

Serialization:

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'item_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ItemModel {
  String id;
  @JsonKey(name: "title")
  String itemName;
  String description;
  @JsonKey(name: "picture")
  String imageUrl;
  String unit;
  double price;

  ItemModel({
    this.id = "",
    required this.itemName,
    required this.description,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.unit,
    required this.price,
  });

  factory ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ItemModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ItemModelToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ItemModel(id: $id, itemName: $itemName, description: $description, imageUrl: $imageUrl, unit: $unit, price: $price)';
  }
}


The Api Structure:

import 'package:lab_app/src/model/category_model.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/model/item_model.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/constants/endpoints.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/home/result/home_result.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/services/http_manager.dart';

class HomeRepository {
  final _httpManager = HttpManager();

  Future<HomeResult<CategoryModel>> getAllCategories() async {
    final result = await _httpManager.restRequest(
      url: EndPoints.getAllCategories,
      method: HttpMethods.post,
    );

    if (result["result"] != null) {
      List<CategoryModel> data =
          (List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(result["result"]))
              .map(CategoryModel.fromJson)
              .toList();

      return HomeResult<CategoryModel>.success(data);
    } else {
      return HomeResult.error(
        "Ocorreu um erro inesperado ao recuperar as categorias",
      );
    }
  }

  Future<HomeResult<ItemModel>> getAllProducts(
      Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
    final result = await _httpManager.restRequest(
      url: HttpMethods.post,
      method: EndPoints.getAllProducts,
      body: body,
    );

    if (result["result"] != null) {
      List<ItemModel> data = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(result["result"])
          .map(ItemModel.fromJson)
          .toList();

      return HomeResult.success(data);
    } else {
      return HomeResult.error(
        "Ocorreu um erro inesperado ao recuperar os produtos",
      );
    }
  }
}

API Call:

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/model/category_model.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/model/item_model.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/home/repository/home_repository.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/home/result/home_result.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/services/utils_services.dart';

int itensPerPage = 6;

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  HomeRepository homeRepository = HomeRepository();
  final utilsServices = UtilsServices();

  List<CategoryModel> allCategories = [];
  List<ItemModel> get allProducts => currentCategory?.items ?? [];
  CategoryModel? currentCategory;

  bool isLoading = false;

  setLoading(bool value) {
    isLoading = value;

    update();
  }

  @override
  onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    getAllCategories();
  }

  selectCategories(CategoryModel categories) {
    currentCategory = categories;
    update();

    getAllProducts();
  }

  Future<void> getAllCategories() async {
    setLoading(true);
    HomeResult<CategoryModel> homeResult =
        await homeRepository.getAllCategories();
    setLoading(false);

    homeResult.when(
      success: (data) {
        allCategories.assignAll(data);

        if (allCategories.isEmpty) return;

        selectCategories(allCategories.first);
      },
      error: (message) {
        utilsServices.showToast(
          label: message,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> getAllProducts() async {
    setLoading(true);
    
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "page": currentCategory!.pagination,
      "categoryId": currentCategory!.id,
      "itemsPerPage": itensPerPage,
    };

    HomeResult<ItemModel> result = await homeRepository.getAllProducts(body);

    setLoading(false);

    result.when(
      success: (data) {
        currentCategory!.items = data;
      },
      error: (message) {
        utilsServices.showToast(label: message);
      },
    );
  }
}

Deployment on gridView:

import 'package:add_to_cart_animation/add_to_cart_animation.dart';
import 'package:add_to_cart_animation/add_to_cart_icon.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/commom_widgets/custom_headline_text.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/commom_widgets/custom_shimmer.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/home/controller/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/home/view/components/category_item.dart';
import 'package:lab_app/src/page/home/view/components/item_tile.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeTab({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeTab> createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  GlobalKey<CartIconKey> globalKeyCartAnimation = GlobalKey<CartIconKey>();

  late Function(GlobalKey) runAddToCartAnimation;

  itemSelectedCartAnimation(GlobalKey globalKey) {
    runAddToCartAnimation(globalKey);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(100),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const CustomHeadlineText(
          textSize: 30,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 16,
              top: 17,
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Badge(
                label: const Text("2"),
                offset: const Offset(9, -12),
                child: AddToCartIcon(
                  key: globalKeyCartAnimation,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_cart_checkout,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 26,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: AddToCartAnimation(
        gkCart: globalKeyCartAnimation,
        previewCurve: Curves.ease,
        previewDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        receiveCreateAddToCardAnimationMethod: (addToCardAnimationMethod) {
          runAddToCartAnimation = addToCardAnimationMethod;
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  hintText: "Pesquise aqui..",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                  ),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GetBuilder<HomeController>(
              builder: (controller) {
                return Container(
                  height: 30,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                  child: !controller.isLoading
                      ? ListView.separated(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                            return CategoryItem(
                              categories: controller.allCategories[index].title,
                              isSelected: controller.allCategories[index] ==
                                  controller.currentCategory,
                              onPressed: () {
                                controller.selectCategories(
                                    controller.allCategories[index]);
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
                              const SizedBox(width: 5),
                          itemCount: controller.allCategories.length,
                        )
                      : ListView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: List.generate(
                            8,
                            (index) => Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              child: CustomShimmer(
                                height: 30,
                                width: 70,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                );
              },
            ),
            GetBuilder<HomeController>(
              builder: (controller) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: !controller.isLoading
                      ? GridView.builder(
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          gridDelegate:
                              const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 9 / 11.5,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                          ),
                          itemCount: controller.allProducts.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ItemTile(
                              items: controller.allProducts[index],
                              cartAnimationMethod: itemSelectedCartAnimation,
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      : GridView.count(
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          childAspectRatio: 9 / 11.5,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          children: List.generate(
                            8,
                            (index) => CustomShimmer(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share specific things : endpoint, api call and creating grid view.

Comment: @Dhiraj Sharma, all the necessary are now added. Thank you for feedback.